# Suppose you toss two fair 6-face dice, and you get $Y_1$ and $Y_2$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let $X = Y_1 + Y_2$. Find the conditional probability $P[Y_2\ge4|X\le7]$. Round your answer to 3 digits.

By drawing a chart for $X=Y_1+Y_2$, we see that $P[Y_2\ge4, X\le7] = 6/36$ and $P[X\le7] = 21/36$ So we get $P[Y_2\ge4|X\le7] = 2/7$ which I rounded to $0.29$. I don't understand why but the Coursera course I'm taking won't accept this.

Comment: Well let's just treat it as simple counting problem, if $Y_2=4$ then 4+1,4+2,4+3 are three possibility for the sum to be less than or equal to 7. For 5, we have 5+1, 5+2. 2 possibilities. For 6, we have 6+1. 1 possibility. Since total sample space is 36. Therefore, (3+2+1)/36

Comment: You're missing the probability that $P(Y_2\ge4)=\frac12$ to give the answer as $\frac17$.

Comment: $0.29$ is only two digits. The question asks for three.

Comment: @DanielMathias you're right I was stuck on a couple other questions where it said round to 2 digits when what they mean was 2 decimal